# How to I fix the image size and position on a bootstrap card template?

Tags: django, image, bootstrap-4, card

Good evening everyone,

I am trying to avoid that the image of a card (implemented through bootstrap) shifts to the top of the card once the user sees the website from a mobile version.

The problem is as follow:

[image: How it looks like]
[image: How I want it to look like also from a mobile phone:]

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                  <div class="row no-gutters">

                      {% if post.immagine %}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <img src="{{ post.immagine.url }}" class="card-img" width="200" height="260">
                        </div>
                      {% else %}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div>
                      {% endif %}

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                       
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.nome }} {{ post.cognome }} -

             

                         </h5>

                          <a href="{% url 'prova-detail' post.pk %}" class="btn btn-dark" style="background-color: #282d4c;">Leggi</a>
                          <p class="card-text"></p>
                      </div>

                        {% else %}

                      <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.nome }} {{ post.cognome }}</h5>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

       {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap consists of 12 cols to render the content

if you write:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>  
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
```

it means that the left column gets 1/3 of the content and the rigth one 2/3.

the md in col-md-* means that this only works for all resolutions bigger than md ( it's tablet i think )

just get rid of the md and it should work

```
<div class="col-4"></div>  
<div class="col-8"></div>
```